# docker-compose copies files as folder

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to copy elasticsearch.yml with CORS enabled from my host to a container using docker-compose volumes option.
But when I copy the config folder it copies the elasticsearch.yml file in it as a folder.

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"

services:  
elasticsearch1:  
    container_name: my_container_name
    image: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m"
    volumes:
      - /config/:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
      - '9300:9300'
```

And this is the error message i get whe running docker-compose up:

> > Exception in thread "main" SettingsException[Failed to load settings from /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml]; nested: IOException[Is a directory];

I also tried copying to tmp folder, and  file was listed as a folder:

> > drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 40 Jul  6 08:25 elasticsearch.yml

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I see you have an elasticsearch.yml directory indicated by the **d** in drwxr-xr-x.

Is the local _elasticsearch.yml_ also a directory?

Comment: It is a file. And I`m using a Windows operating system.

Comment: So the `config` dir is in root? I guess it should be `./config:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/`

Comment: Now the temp config folder  is created but is empty

Answer (score 3):

With Docker for Windows and Docker for Mac, you are running docker inside of a VM and mounting directories from inside that VM into your container. When the file or directory doesn't exist inside the VM, it will get mounted as an empty folder by Docker as a default behavior (this behavior appears to be changing with swarm mode).

To get a folder from the windows host into the VM where it can then be mapped into a container, you need to go into the docker settings and configure your shared drives:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#shared-drives

Comment: In my case, I had changed my Windows password the day before I ran into this problem. I thought restarting my PC would be sufficient but it wasn't enough. I needed to open my Docker settings and choose Reset Credentials.